# How to Change Git-TF checkin message format

Tags: tfs, git-tf

Does anyone know how to configure the auto-generated message that is created on a git-tf checkin command to TFS?

I would like to have more control over that to allow for adding a comment during checkin.

The agile process system that my company uses allows adding a task number in front of a comment, and then will associate the source code with the task in the agile system.

Anyone have any ideas? Anyone have any customized git-tf source?

Answer (score 5):

As mention in [this thread](http://gittf.codeplex.com/discussions/401969), you can try!

> > I've upgraded to the latest version of `git-tf` and noticed that it generates a different comment for a tfs changeset after doing a checkin than the previous version (I'm using the `--deep` option, no message provided with the command).
> >     Is there a way to revert to the 'clean' (without the commit guid, author, commiter) comment from git?
>
> Yes, You can use the `--no-metadata` flag when checking in and it will revert back to the "clean" comment.

So you don't have much control on the comment, but at least you can reuse git comments.

There is a request for [making that option the default](http://gittf.codeplex.com/workitem/51).